# Eclipse: Local Debug (not remote) "Cannot connect to VM"

Tags: java, eclipse

I am switching from IntelliJ Idea to Eclipse (yea, I know... long story). Seems that I can only debug an application once. After the first time, I try to debug again, I get the error:

```
Launching <app> has encountered a problem
Cannot connect to VM

Address already in use: JVM_Bind
```

[image]

If I shut down Eclipse and restart I can once again debug the app once. This doesn't affect running.

I have a feeling that a thread in my app isn't shutting down, but don't know a good way to test that and/or completely kill the process w/o shutting down Eclipse each time.

Eclipse Version: 4.2.1 Build id: M20120914-1800 (Juno?)

JRE: 1.6.0_32-b05

NOTE: this is running as "Java Application" and not a "Remote Java Application".

UPDATE: Updated to JDK 1.7x and it seems to be working now...

Comment: 1) There were a number of bugs discovered in JRE 1.6 **AND** it is end of life anyway.
2) I suspect that you app debug session did **NOT** finish before you are attempting to debug it again

Comment: Thanks. I am going to try using more recent JRE...

Comment: Interestingly enough, installed 1.7.x and now It works great...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to a JDK 7 seemed to fix this issue...

Answer (score 0):

JVM_Bind binds to an socket that is already in use on your computer.

I remember this problem in using Skype or Outlook to same time.

Comment: Don't run Skype and I shut down Outlook, but no luck.

Comment: what sais "netstat -nab" about port 1098?

Answer (score 0):

Your debugged application is not yet shut down.

Go to debug-view and terminate the application manual.

Comment: Shutting down manually same issue (clicking on the Terminate button). Won't launch the 2nd time. Has got to be something odd w/ my application, a thread that isn't shutting down... Odd that this doesn't happen in INtelliJ Idea though.

Comment: Very much. Looks like upgrading my JVM fixed it though.